# Parquet: Recursive Thrift Data Structure

Tags: java, recursion, thrift, parquet

I have the following (simplified) thrift definition. It contains a recursive tree-like structure:

```
namespace java com.test.thrift

struct B {
  1: list<A> aList,
  2: i16 label
}

struct A {
  1: list<B> bList,
  2: i16 label
}
```

Converting the Java-Representation of this definition causes a stack-overflow (endless-loop)

```
val sType = org.apache.parquet.thrift.ThriftSchemaConverter.toStructType(classOf[com.test.thrift.A])
```

which is invoked by creating an instance of

```
org.apache.parquet.thrift.ThriftParquetWriter
```

The recursion is arround:

```
at org.apache.parquet.thrift.ThriftSchemaConverter.toStructType(ThriftSchemaConverter.java:82)
at org.apache.parquet.thrift.ThriftSchemaConverter.toThriftField(ThriftSchemaConverter.java:116)
at org.apache.parquet.thrift.ThriftSchemaConverter.toThriftField(ThriftSchemaConverter.java:131)
```

Is there any way to work with recursive data structures in Parquet?

Thanks for you support

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a reference loop, which is what leads you to the stack overflow exception (the serializer follows the references for as long as it can before things blow up).

A possible solutions to avoid running into this could be to add an identifier field to each label, and use these in the `aList` or `bList` instead of a reference.